# Keras model not running in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a model that I am trying to classify the modes of action with the IMU. The data is in .csv format. Everything was fine up to this part, but in the model building part, it does not progress after a while. what is the reason of this?

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, activation='relu')) 
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(15, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(NUM_GESTURES, activation='softmax'))  
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mse', metrics=['mae'])
history = model.fit(inputs_train, outputs_train, epochs=600, batch_size=1, validation_data=(inputs_validate, outputs_validate))

Epoch 1/300
WARNING:tensorflow:Entity <function Function._initialize_uninitialized_variables.<locals>.initialize_variables at 0x7f7e15b0b5f0> could not be transformed and will be executed as-is. Please report this to the AutoGraph team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output. Cause: module 'gast' has no attribute 'Num'
WARNING: Entity <function Function._initialize_uninitialized_variables.<locals>.initialize_variables at 0x7f7e15b0b5f0> could not be transformed and will be executed as-is. Please report this to the AutoGraph team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output. Cause: module 'gast' has no attribute 'Num'
```

Comment: Maybe you need different version of gast, https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/32319,

Comment: @Cansu Başer, Did you tried as suggested above?

Comment: Yes I tried. it actually works, but my problem was with the previous code cells. IMU data was insufficient to detect motion. I updated my data set.

Comment: @Cansu Başer, That's good to hear. If your issue is resolved, please post your solution in the answer section for the benefit of community. Thanks!